# CORS issue using SignalR through Kubernetes

Tags: angular, kubernetes, .net-core, cors, signalr

I'm trying to connect my angular FE with my signalR hub in my backend (.NET core) that is hosted inside kubernetes, when I try I get this error message:
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Does anyone know how to solve this? this is my configuration:

```
services.AddCors(x => 
    x.AddPolicy("my-cors", y=> y.WithOrigins("https://subdomain.mydomain.com")
    .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()));

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("my-cors");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/messageHub");
});


[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class MessageHub : Hub { ... }
```

In my ingress configuration I have this:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-expose-headers: "*"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://subdomain.mydomain.com"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "ingress-sps-tst/tls-secret"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
```

From the angular FE i do this:

```
const hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(this.signalREndpoint +'/messageHub', {
      accessTokenFactory: () => token,
    }).build();

hubConnection.start().then(....)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same issue when configuring SignalR for my project using SPA framework. But my error information is a little different from you `Request header field x-signalr-user-agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

After spending a lot of time for research in the internet and Ingress Nginx document. I can solve problems with CORS policy configuration.

In your annotations section of metadata using following config:

```
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

    # CORS for api setup
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,X-SignalR-User-Agent"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
```

As you can see `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers` in document they say the default value does not include what SignalR need **X-SignalR-User-Agent**. Read about it in [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors)

Using this config now my project can run without any problem.

[image: Network result tab]